# What (and Where will I find) the best simple text editor for my Ubuntu phone

Tags: phone, editor

I have the Meizu Pro 5 and accidentaly deleted my text editor. I can't
find another simple text editor for my Ubuntu touch phone. Nothing in either App store!!

Answer (score 0):

You have [edit](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.developer.pawstr.edit) and [uwriter](https://uappexplorer.com/app/uwp.costales) (html format) in the official apps store.